# video streaming in nodejs through fs module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to stream video in node.js through fs module & I have tried the below code.

```
app.get('/video', function(req, res) {
  const path = 'assets/sample.mp4'
  const stat = fs.statSync(path)
  const fileSize = stat.size
  const range = req.headers.range
  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
    const start = parseInt(parts[0],10);
    const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1],10) : fileSize-1
    const chunksize = (end-start)+1
    const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(206, head)
    file.pipe(res)
  } else {
       const head = {
         'Content-Length': fileSize,
         'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
       }
       res.writeHead(200, head)
       fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  }
})
```

My video 'sample.mp4' size is: 1055736 bytes which is 1 MB. But when I run the code, I found that in starting the `start` variable is 0, `end`  variable is 1055735 & `chunksize` is 1055736. And if you look at **Content-Range** header, which will be equals to below value in starting.

> Content-Range : **'bytes 0-1055735/1055736'**

I want to stream my video in chunks one after another instead of wait for the whole video to load. But I think above code will not do the same.

Can anyone please tell me, Is this code correct for video streaming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose `req.headers.range === "bytes=0-" `?

Comment: sorry? your answer is not enough clear.

Comment: It's not an answer. Maybe a hint, but not an answer. It's a question. So is the request header `Range` equals `"bytes=0-"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, except for the one thing: usually a browser sends you `Range: bytes=0-` in requests for a video. From this header your code

```
const start = parseInt(parts[0],10);
const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1],10) : fileSize-1
```

gives you `start === 0` and `end === fileSize-1` and the `chunksize` of a file size. Because `parts[1]` is always falsy. So it is **you** who decides to send the file in one big chunk, not the browser. The browser is ready to receive a `206 Partial Content`, but you are not sending it. Try

```
const preferred_chunksize = 100000
let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1],10) : start + preferred_chunksize
if( end > fileSize-1 ) end = fileSize-1
const chunksize = end-start+1
```

The `preferred_chunksize` can be anything from 1 to `fileSize`, depending on your network conditions. I tried `preferred_chunksize = 1000` - it's slow. I didn't try `preferred_chunksize = 1` - because it will be **extremely** slow and will lead to millions of requests. `preferred_chunksize` between 100 000 and 10 000 000 looks acceptable.

But, actually, if you'll try your code on a big file, your will notice no excessive memory usage, and that browsers will start playing your video file right away, without waiting

> for the whole video to load

Even if you'll skip the `end` part all together (as it is already done in your version of code), and simplify your code using:

```
const end = fileSize-1
const chunksize = end-start+1
```

it will do.
And, as I know from the original version of your question, your are writing a tutorial, so for your purposes it will do just fine.

PS. And of course in production code you'd better check if `Range` header is malformed

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But I don't know what `preferred_chunksize` should I use. Can you please edit your answer and tell me also that?